# Change URL after $.when

Tags: jquery, promise, redirect

When I run the following code, my console will display 'HERE', followed by my data object, followed by 'DONE', as expected.

```
var promises = [];
promises.push(getData('XYZ', function (data) {
  console.log(data);
}));
console.log('HERE');
$.when.apply($, promises).done(function () {
  console.log('DONE');
});
```

But when I do the following, it returns 'HERE', followed by an *empty* data object, then 'DONE' and the page is redirected. Why is my object empty?

```
var promises = [];
promises.push(getData('XYZ', function(data) {
  console.log(data);
}));
console.log('HERE');
$.when.apply($, promises).done(function() {
  console.log('DONE');
  window.location.replace("/")
});
```

I know that I can do the redirect in the callback, but I am curious as to why this doesn't work. my getData() function is below. No error is logged.

```
function getData(id, callback) {
  var url = "/api/id/" + id;
  console.log(url);
  return $.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: url,
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (result) {
      callback(result);
    },
    error: function (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: Does `getData()` return a promise? If it does not return a promise, then the `promises` array is immediately resolved, which might explain why the page is redirected first without waiting for the callback from `getData()` to be invoked. There is also no `HERE` being console logged in your second example: where is the line supposed to be?

Comment: @Terry My apologies. Left out the 'HERE' in the second example. Edited the post. As for the getData() function, it returns an $.ajax call. I believe that means it returns a promise?

Comment: @Jeto So by that conclusion it must be something wrong with my server side logic then, right?

Comment: @EvanHessler I don't see how it could be related to that. Did you try replacing your URL with that placeholder one in your own code? What is the result?

Comment: @Jeto Just did. When I replace my URL with your placeholder, it works...